# Inability to scroll after turning div from absolute to fixed positioning using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, css-position

I have a div that gets a 'fixed' class added to it once the user scrolls past a certain point in the parent div. The fixed class simply changes the child div from absolute positioning to fixed positioning.

However, a problem occurs when the user scrolls to a certain point when the 'fixed' class is added (as specified by the 'begin variable' in the js). The user loses the ability to scroll up or down for a number of seconds. And to make matters more complicated, this problem only occurs on the first of six parent divs that uses this code.

Here's the jquery code that adds the 'fixed' class:

```
var begin = 164;

$("#portfolio_window").scroll(function () {     
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= begin) {
        $('.details').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.details').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

If I change the 'begin' variable to something like 600, the user loses the ability to scroll around 600px from the top of the div.

You can try to reproduce the problem at http://dev.zachboth.com/

Here's the easiest way that I've been able to reproduce the problem:

- Use Safari
- Clicking 'Various Logos' in the 'Work' section
- Scrolling down quickly once the 'Various Logos' section appears
- It may take several attempts to actually have the problem occur

Answer (score 0):

I can explain your problem:

The problem is that on the "page" you mention being broken has you scrolling in div#portfolio_window. The position:fixed element you mentioned is positioned relative to the window. When you scroll on that element, it's trying to scroll the window (not the parent div).

http://jsfiddle.net/NThY7/

The solution is a bit more involved. I'll hop back on later with a solution.

Comment: Interesting. So because the main window is given "overflow:hidden" when the projects slide in, the viewport is in effect given the "overflow:hidden" attribute temporarily when the div becomes fixed? That is until it realizes that you can scroll within the "#portfolio_window."

Any ideas on how to fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think a little DOM re-architecting  is in order. The way it functions is really neat, but you'll have to achieve the effect some other way. A quick (hacky) fix would be to use suedo fixed positioning on the fixed element (container.onscroll=updateSuedoFixedTop).